# Mac OS X on Ubuntu through VMware?

Tags: 12.04, vmware, macosx

Can I install Mac OS on my PC through VMware. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as a host operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install Mac OS on your PC by using VM Ware, but you need Mac OS VMware image files to install Mac OS in VMware.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do it. [Follow this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Player) guide to install vmware player on Ubuntu 12.04.